# Google Map getMapAsync() NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

After I change getMap() to getMapAsync() and implements OnMapReadyCallback I get the error NullPointerException.

here the logcat

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference at pym.example.com.fypv2.callme.Callme.onCreate(Callme.java:117)`

here the code

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

// Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

and the OnMapReady

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled?
OnCreate()?

Comment: yes, before that I call it in the OnCreate() but throw me an NullPointerException. So I call in the OnMapReady then problem solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` after your map ready in `onMapReady`.

Change Your code as below:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: glade to know it's helps you.